# Akka actors remote doesn't work (in Play framework)

Tags: playframework, akka, playframework-2.1

When trying to run the code below:

```
ActorRef parserActor1 =system.actorFor("akka://ParserActorsSystem@10.0.0.9:2552/user/ParserMainActor");
System.out.println("*$^%$^%$^"+parserActor1);   
parserActor1.tell("Please parse!", mainActor);
```

The first and the second line work well - that means that the remoting is working fine (I think). 
On the 3rd line, I get the error "swallowing exception during message sent".

I'm working with akka-remote version 2.1.1. What may be the problem?

The application.conf contains:

```
    akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
      hostname = "10.0.0.8"
      port = 2552
    }
 }
}
```

This is the exact error: "[ERROR] [03/06/2013 16:15:42.129] [New I/O  worker #1] [akka://ParserActorsSystem@10.0.0.9:2552/user/ParserMainActor] swallowing exception during message send
java.lang.IllegalStateException: await*() in I/O thread causes a dead lock or sudden performance drop. Use addListener() instead or call await*() from a different thread."

Thanks a lot,
Aviad

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting a Netty quirk which is exposed by Play in collaboration with Akka remoting: http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/1042-Netty-pipeline-needs-an-executionHandler